# Equation Containing Sum of Squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have a question for the following equation:

$$ a^{2} + c^{2} = p (b^{2} + d^{2}) + 1 ,$$

where $a, b, c, d$ are integers, and $p$ is prime number such that $p \equiv 3 (mod \, 4).$ My question is that for each $p,$ could we find infinitely many solutions?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no restrictions on $a,b,c,d$, just pick $c=d=0$ and this reduces to the Pell equation $a^2 - pb^2 = 1$ which always has infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Fermat's_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) and more some [works](http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/124/lectures/lecture21/lecture21/node2.html),

> A number $ n$ is a sum of two squares if and only if all prime factors of $ n$ of the form $ 4m+3$ have even exponent in the prime factorization of $ n$.

So we need $p(b^2+d^2) + 1$ to be satify the condition. If we choosce $b=2m, d=2n$ we get $4(n^2+m^2)p +1$. If it is prime, it must be 1(mod 4), hence must be sum of two squares $a$ and $c$.

So I can't proof it, but it is enough to proof that:

for any prime $p=4q+1$, there is infinitely many prime numbers that match to $4(n^2+m^2)p +1$.

Hope someone can prove it.

Comment: While this observation is certainly true, I'm not sure it's very helpful as the new condition seems quite a bit stricter than the original.